# Difference between "tournament", "competition" and "match"

Tags: word-choice, differences

I was just reading the article about [TopCoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topcoder). Before this article I thought a tournament and a competition is the same. What is the difference between *tournament*, *competition* and *match*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Match** is "a formal contest in which two or more persons or teams compete".

**Tournament** consists of multiple matches between contestants and comes from "contest between groups of knights on horseback. Modern use, in ref. to games of skill, is recorded from 1761."

**Competition** does not have such a problem with its meaning of "a contest for something" which is from 1610s.

*Differences and relationships*:
So, *match* is a different animal (you can not call a *match* neither a *tournament* nor *competition*).
Every *tournament* is a *competition*, but not every *competition* is a *tournament*.

You can also look at related term: *championship*.

References are from etymonline entries for match, tournament and competition.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate beyond the definitions already provided, a tournament generally refers to a specific format of competition, where competitors engage in a series of matches to determine the winner(s).

There are several [types](http://www.afterschoolpa.com/typesoftournaments_a.html) of tournaments (single elimination, double elimination, round robin, etc.), but generally speaking the goal of the tournament is to provide overall winners through a gradual sorting process based upon success within the individual tournament matches.

A competition can be any of the different types of tournaments, or it can be something less structured (such as two teams playing a single match).

Answer (score 1):

First, a "match" is usually between two parties as contestant, where as a "tournament" or a "competition" is for multiple contestant.

A tournament, is a series of matches. There are generally a large number of contestants

A competition can include a tournament, or a match. It's a more general sense, and includes anything, in which there is one or more parties contesting. A competition can consist of only *one* contestant, which "tournament" and "matches" can't have. That's the only differences I can think up of.

Comment: How about comparing to championship?

Answer (score 0):

A *tournament* is a contest where teams or individuals compete but not necessarily against each other. It usually lasts a short period of time. Competitors are eliminated along the way, until you get to the final of two teams or competitors where the eventual winner is decided.

A *competition* on the other hand is a contest where all participants competes against one another, usually on a home and away basis. It generally lasts for weeks or months. No one is eliminated and the winner is the one that has accrued the most points.

Comment: Please cite reputable sources or specific expertise to back up your answer.